# Mac crash report info - what can I learn from it?

Tags: macos, mac, crash

My Mac (MacBook Pro, 10.7.3 OS) is crashing a couple of times a day. I started this behaviour just recently, and for no *apparent* reason. I've done a disk check and it all seems fine. When it crashes, the screen goes black and I have to long-press the power button to force a restart.

When the Mac restarts, I get prompted to send data on the crash to Apple. Is there anything in this data that would indicate *to me* the cause of the problem?  Faulty IO board, memory parity corruption, disk problems etc?

This is one of the recent reports:

```
    Interval Since Last Panic Report:  14361 sec
    Panics Since Last Report:          1
    Anonymous UUID:                    128DD708-7642-4EF6-B7BA-51980C7033C4

    Thu Feb  9 20:36:45 2012
    panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f8098b907): NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xc0000000 0xffffff8115549000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4
    Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
    0xffffff80f15fae70 : 0xffffff8000220702 
    0xffffff80f15faef0 : 0xffffff7f8098b907 
    0xffffff80f15faf80 : 0xffffff7f80a7ba64 
    0xffffff80f15fafd0 : 0xffffff7f80a7bb24 
    0xffffff80f15fb030 : 0xffffff7f80d28749 
    0xffffff80f15fb170 : 0xffffff7f80a9abad 
    0xffffff80f15fb1a0 : 0xffffff7f80995282 
    0xffffff80f15fb250 : 0xffffff7f80990b84 
    0xffffff80f15fb440 : 0xffffff7f80991e57 
    0xffffff80f15fb500 : 0xffffff7f817fc336 
    0xffffff80f15fb610 : 0xffffff7f817fc863 
    0xffffff80f15fb630 : 0xffffff7f817c2498 
    0xffffff80f15fb640 : 0xffffff7f817fbe67 
    0xffffff80f15fb650 : 0xffffff7f817c1aca 
    0xffffff80f15fb660 : 0xffffff7f817fc842 
    0xffffff80f15fb680 : 0xffffff7f817c6220 
    0xffffff80f15fb6c0 : 0xffffff7f817c302f 
    0xffffff80f15fb6f0 : 0xffffff7f8182bc3e 
    0xffffff80f15fb770 : 0xffffff7f8181644b 
    0xffffff80f15fb7d0 : 0xffffff7f81816846 
    0xffffff80f15fb820 : 0xffffff7f81816abb 
    0xffffff80f15fb8b0 : 0xffffff7f8181780f 
    0xffffff80f15fb8e0 : 0xffffff7f817cf0b0 
    0xffffff80f15fbaa0 : 0xffffff7f81817f68 
    0xffffff80f15fbb60 : 0xffffff7f817cc119 
    0xffffff80f15fbbc0 : 0xffffff800065239e 
    0xffffff80f15fbbe0 : 0xffffff8000652c7a 
    0xffffff80f15fbc40 : 0xffffff800065341b 
    0xffffff80f15fbd80 : 0xffffff80002a3b78 
    0xffffff80f15fbe80 : 0xffffff8000223006 
    0xffffff80f15fbeb0 : 0xffffff8000214829 
    0xffffff80f15fbf10 : 0xffffff800021bb58 
    0xffffff80f15fbf70 : 0xffffff80002aeb80 
    0xffffff80f15fbfb0 : 0xffffff80002d8383 
          Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
             com.apple.NVDAResman(7.1.8)[94BA87BA-B128-3310-9860-98EC67AB7FAF]@0xffffff7f8092b000->0xffffff7f80c04fff
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.6.8)[F63D4ABE-42DA-33EF-BADD-3415B0CB0179]@0xffffff7f808b6000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.2)[4B3F84DC-18B3-3897-BC56-4E3940878047]@0xffffff7f80919000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.2)[FE536983-1897-3D6B-965E-24B5A67080DA]@0xffffff7f808e1000
             com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal(7.1.8)[7596DB8C-AE9D-3C87-B11A-0ED8F940CAF8]@0xffffff7f80c05000->0xffffff7f80f26fff
                dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(7.1.8)[94BA87BA-B128-3310-9860-98EC67AB7FAF]@0xffffff7f8092b000
             com.apple.GeForce(7.1.8)[61FD1644-DA39-3645-9380-7F490FB000DB]@0xffffff7f817c1000->0xffffff7f81880fff
                dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(7.1.8)[94BA87BA-B128-3310-9860-98EC67AB7FAF]@0xffffff7f8092b000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.2)[4B3F84DC-18B3-3897-BC56-4E3940878047]@0xffffff7f80919000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.6.8)[F63D4ABE-42DA-33EF-BADD-3415B0CB0179]@0xffffff7f808b6000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.2)[FE536983-1897-3D6B-965E-24B5A67080DA]@0xffffff7f808e1000

    BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

    Mac OS version:
    11D50

    Kernel version:
    Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64
    Kernel UUID: 7B6546C7-70E8-3ED8-A6C3-C927E4D3D0D6
    System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

    System uptime in nanoseconds: 17972826039499
    last loaded kext at 14605059483721: com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1.0.0d22 (addr 0xffffff7f807e4000, size 36864)
    last unloaded kext at 14667664270296: com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily   1.0.0d22 (addr 0xffffff7f807e4000, size 36864)
    loaded kexts:
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.1.4
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.1.4
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.1.4
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.1.4
    com.apani.nke.ApaniKernel   3.3
    foo.tun 1.0
    foo.tap 1.0
    com.vara.driver.VaraAudio   1.0.3
    com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.0
    com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 9.8
    com.apple.nke.asp_tcp   6.0.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.4d0
    com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
    com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.1.7f9
    com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.1.7f9
    com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
    com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.42
    com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
    com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.26
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   7.1.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 7.1.8
    com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.1d2
    com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
    com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.2
    com.apple.GeForce   7.1.8
    com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.5d4
    com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.3
    com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.0.16
    com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  225.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.0.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 225.2
    com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
    com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
    com.apple.BootCache 33
    com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.0.3
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.5.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.0.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.8.9
    com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   513.20.19
    com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.0.8b2
    com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.5.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.2.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.5.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.4
    com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.4
    com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.6
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.4
    com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.5
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 167.3.0
    com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
    com.apple.security.quarantine   1.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   167.3.0
    com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
    com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.1.7f9
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
    com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.3f12
    com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
    com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.4
    com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc6
    com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
    com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.1.7f9
    com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.1.7f9
    com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.0.16
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.1d8
    com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 4.7.5d4
    com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.0.16
    com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.3
    com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    7.1.8
    com.apple.NVDAResman    7.1.8
    com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.2
    com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
    com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.3f12
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.3f12
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.3f12
    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.0.3
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.0.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 227.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.4.5
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   4.5.3
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  4.5.8
    com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 403
    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.0.3
    com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
    com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7
    com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7
    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.0.3
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.5.8
    com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.5
    com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   412.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.0d5
    com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.7
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.5.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.5.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
    com.apple.security.sandbox  177.3
    com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
    com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
    com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331
    com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7
    com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.4
    com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.8
    com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
    System Profile:
    Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0C, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.53 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f15
    Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB
    Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
    Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533641465238432D47372020
    Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533641465238432D47372020
    AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.19)
    Bluetooth: Version 4.0.3f12, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
    Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
    Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5055GSXF, 500.11 GB
    Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
    USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
    USB Device: Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM), 0x045e  (Microsoft Corporation), 0x0040, 0xfa140000 / 6
    USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfa130000 / 5
    USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
    USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0xfa113000 / 9
    USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0237, 0xfa120000 / 3
    USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
    USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0xfd110000 / 4
    USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 3
```

Comment: Yes. You can google for selected parts of it to see what others have written. Besides that, it's very low level technical information, and if you have to ask this question, probably not helpful to you. You could add it to your question (indent all lines by four spaces for `monospace` text, maybe it's something one of the other users here has seen before, or has an idea what you could do.

Comment: It seems to be a known (if not officially acknowledged) issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3114550?start=0&tstart=0